# Conditionally create a dataframe collapse a collapse a column while truncating actual dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, cluster-analysis, dcast

I've a dataframe as under:

```
+------+----+----------+----------+
| from | to | priority | distance |
+------+----+----------+----------+
|    1 |  3 |        1 |       10 |
|    1 |  5 |        1 |       10 |
|    2 |  7 |        1 |       10 |
|    3 |  9 |        1 |       15 |
|    4 |  8 |        2 |       20 |
|    5 |  6 |        2 |       20 |
|    5 |  1 |        2 |       30 |
|    6 |  2 |        2 |       30 |
|    6 |  4 |        3 |       40 |
|    7 |  2 |        3 |       40 |
|    8 |  3 |        3 |       50 |
|    9 |  5 |        3 |       60 |
|   10 |    |        3 |          |
|   12 | 11 |        7 |        9 |
+------+----+----------+----------+
```

Its sorted by the priority and distances

I want to collapse the to column based on the following criterias:

1. Every unique values in the `to` will be grouped with the corresponding `from` (example row 1 in the table below)

   ```
   +--------------+----------+
   | from_parent  | to_child |
   +--------------+----------+
   |            1 |      3,5 |
   +--------------+----------+
   ```

   If a value has alredy been grouped in the `to_child` (in our case the number 3) and if it also appears in the `from` of the main table and if its corresponding `to` is a new value, a value that hasn't ever appeared in the `from_parent` or `to_child`, then that value should appear independently in from_parent
   For instance from our table,

   ```
   +------+----+----------+----------+
   | from | to | priority | distance |
   +------+----+----------+----------+
   |    3 |  9 |        1 |       15 |
   +------+----+----------+----------+
   ```

   the value 9 should appear independetly in the new table as under:

   ```
   +--------------+----------+
   | from_parent  | to_child |
   +--------------+----------+
   |            9 |          |
   +--------------+----------+
   ```

but if the value 9 were to later appear in a `to` column it should be added to the `to_child` cluster and the previous value should be removed, so what I mean by this is that if 9 appeared as `to` for a `from` of 1 later  on, the the correponsing `to_child` value of 1 should be `3,5,9`

so the final table should be as under

```
+--------------+----------+
| from_parent  | to_child |
+--------------+----------+
|            1 |      3,5 |
|            2 |        7 |
|            4 |        8 |
|            6 |          |
|            9 |          |
|           10 |          |
|           12 |       11 |
+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: The values reachable from `1` are `3, 5, 6, 9, 2, 4, 7, 8`. Do you want them all in the `to` corresponding to `from == 1`?

Comment: No, I would want to group sequentially meaning in the case of `1` as its corresponding to is `3,5` just display `3,5` 

I wouldn't want a value that previously appeared in the `to_child` or `from_parent` to repeat again

Answer (score 3):

I will use package `igraph` to solve the problem in the question since this is a graph theory problem.

First, construct the graph from the first 2 columns of the input data.frame.

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df1[1:2], directed = TRUE)
plot(g, edge.curved = TRUE, edge.arrow.size = 0.5)
```

[image]

Now get the paths from each of the vertices in `df1$from`. The paths are obtained with a breadth-first search, function `bfs`.

```
paths_list <- vector("list", length = length(V(g)))
i <- 0L
for(v in V(g)){
  i <- i + 1L
  ord <- bfs(g, root = v, neimode = "out",
             unreachable = FALSE, dist = TRUE)$dist
  ord <- ord[is.finite(ord)]
  paths_list[[i]] <- ord
}

from <- lapply(paths_list, function(x) names(x)[1])
to <- lapply(paths_list, function(x) paste(names(x)[x != 0], collapse = ","))
res <- data.frame(from = unlist(from), to = unlist(to), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
res <- res[nchar(res$from) != 0, ]

res
#   from              to
#1     1 3,5,6,9,2,4,7,8
#2     2               7
#3     3 9,5,1,6,2,4,7,8
#4     4 8,3,9,5,1,6,2,7
#5     5 1,6,2,3,4,7,8,9
#6     6 2,4,7,8,3,9,5,1
#7     7               2
#8     8 3,9,5,1,6,2,4,7
#9     9 5,1,6,2,3,4,7,8
#10   10                
#11   12              11
```